# windowed linear regressions when the desired 'window' is a timeframe, not a number of observations

Tags: python, pandas, scipy.stats

I have a time series of data whereby the timeperiod interval of each row from the preceding row is not fixed.  One observation may be 1 second or 10 seconds or 2 minutes etc since the previous observation.

```
time                        observation
2021-01-24 23:03:44+00:00   3838.25
2021-01-24 23:03:47+00:00   3838.18
2021-01-24 23:03:48+00:00   3838.25
2021-01-24 23:03:52+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:03:54+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:03:55+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:03:58+00:00   3838.72
2021-01-24 23:03:59+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:04:00+00:00   3838.62
2021-01-24 23:04:01+00:00   3838.25
2021-01-24 23:04:02+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:04:03+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:04:06+00:00   3838.25
2021-01-24 23:04:07+00:00   3838.5
2021-01-24 23:04:08+00:00   3838.38
2021-01-24 23:04:13+00:00   3838.53
(> 1 million rows, btw)
```

I am looking to do a rolling regression to determine the slope of the data over a given time period (window).  I need this data to determine whether the observations are rising or falling over a stipulated period.

For weighted average functions I have successfully used the 'rolling' function which enables me to stipulate a timeframe.  Pandas will look back and select only those datapoints within the stipulated timeframe window irrespective as to their interval:

```
    for timeframe in ['30s', '1Min', '2Min', '3Min', '4Min', '5Min']:
        df[timeframe] = df.rolling(timeframe).observation.mean()
```

I have been researching windowed linear regression and to my limited understanding it seems that the "window" is definable only as a *number of observations*, rather than a *timeframe* above.  This is problematic for my data as 10 observations could cover a period of 30 minutes or 3 seconds etc.

So finally, my question is this - what is the correct way to implement windowed linear regressions whereby the 'window' is a timeframe, not a number of observations.

For bonus points - I am also looking to do windowed/rolling differences on the same dataset - it's a lot harder than it looks having to use custom functions and .apply(myfunc) on very large datasets - it's taking forever to complete - is there a better way?